# Move content from div1 to div2 in a loop

Tags: jquery, foreach, append

I searched for a solution but couldn't find it and kind stuck with this as the loop is generating but i'm not getting the result i want.

Here is the situation: A parent div with child-1 and child-2 are in a loop. I need to move content from child-2 to child-1 in a loop.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

```js
$('.parent').each(function(){
  $('.link').appendTo('.child-1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class='parent'>
 <p class="child-1"> Move link one here </p>
 <p class="child-2">  
  <a class="link" href="#ID-1"> link one </a> 
 </p>
</div>


<div class='parent'>
 <p class="child-1"> Move link two here </p>
 <p class="child-2">  
  <a class="link" href="#ID-2"> link two </a>
 </p>
</div>


<div class='parent'>
 <p class="child-1"> Move link three here </p>
 <p class="child-2">  
  <a class="link" href="#ID-3"> link three</a> 
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is appending all the elements with class "link" to all the children with class ".child-1":

```
$('.link').appendTo('.child-1');
```

What you should do instead is limit the elements to the descendants of each parent, using jQuery's [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.link').appendTo($(this).find('.child-1'));
});
```

```js
$('.parent').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.link').appendTo($(this).find('.child-1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <p class="child-1">Move link one here</p>
  <p class="child-2">
    <a class="link" href="#ID-1"> link one </a> 
  </p>
</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <p class="child-1">Move link two here</p>
  <p class="child-2">
    <a class="link" href="#ID-2"> link two </a>
  </p>
</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <p class="child-1">Move link three here</p>
  <p class="child-2">
    <a class="link" href="#ID-3"> link three</a> 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a loop inside your child 2 div, try this code:

```js
//loop in child-2 div
$('.child-2').each(function(i, item) {
  //get the parent element and find the child-1, the child-1 append the html of child-2
  $(this).parent().find('.child-1').html($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class='parent'>
 <p class="child-1"> Move link one here </p>
 <p class="child-2">  
  <a class="link" href="#ID-1"> link one </a> 
 </p>
</div>


<div class='parent'>
 <p class="child-1"> Move link two here </p>
 <p class="child-2">  
  <a class="link" href="#ID-2"> link two </a>
 </p>
</div>


<div class='parent'>
 <p class="child-1"> Move link three here </p>
 <p class="child-2">  
  <a class="link" href="#ID-3"> link three</a> 
 </p>
</div>
```